# Need help searching for a array of bytes in another process - C windows programming

Tags: c, windows, api

```
/* Preprocessor directives : */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Contants : */

#define BASE_ADDRESS 0xFFFB0000

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Struct for use in this small debugger */

typedef struct MEMORY_ADDRESSES
{
    void * Addresses[10];

    BYTE Storage[10];

} ProcessMem;

ProcessMem MyProcess[1] = {};

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Function Prototypes : */

HANDLE GetProcess( char * ProcessName );
static void DebuggerInit( HANDLE MyProcess, ProcessMem * WriteToStruct, ProcessMem ReadStructInfo );

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Main entry point */

int main( )
{
    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Finds the minesweeper game */

    HANDLE MineSweeper;

    do
    {
        if ( ( MineSweeper = GetProcess( "MineSweeper.exe" ) ) != NULL ) { break; }
        Sleep(1000);
    } while (1);

    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Initializes the information we need in our struct */

    DebuggerInit( MineSweeper, &MyProcess[0], MyProcess[0] );

    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Print out the information we gathered */

    int offset = 0;

    ProcessMem Referencer;

    for(; offset < 10; offset++) { fprintf(stdout, "\t %p = %2X \n", &Referencer.Addresses[offset], Referencer.Storage[offset]); }


    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Close the process handle to avoid nasty memory leaks */

    CloseHandle( MineSweeper );

    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Exit the proccess with 0, as required by the function declaration */

    return 0;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

HANDLE GetProcess( char * ProcessName )
{

    HANDLE hProcessSnap;
    HANDLE hProcess;
    HANDLE DummyHandle = NULL;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;

    /* Take a snapshot of all processes in the system. */
    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    if( hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        return DummyHandle;
    }

    /* Set the size of the structure before using it. */
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );

    if( !Process32First( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) )
    {
    CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Walk through the snapshot, and return the process handle when
       found. */

    do
    {
        if (strcmp(pe32.szExeFile, ProcessName) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );
            hProcess = OpenProcess( PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID );
            return hProcess;
        }
    } while( Process32Next( hProcessSnap, &pe32 ) );

  CloseHandle( hProcessSnap );

  return DummyHandle;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

static void DebuggerInit( HANDLE MyProcess, ProcessMem * WriteToStruct, ProcessMem ReadStructInfo )
{
    /* -------------------------------*/

    DWORD   dwErr;
    BYTE    abErrMsg[128];

    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Stores 10 bytes from the process in tempStorage */

    if ( !ReadProcessMemory( MyProcess, (PCVOID)BASE_ADDRESS, WriteToStruct->Storage, 10, NULL ) )
    {

        dwErr = GetLastError();

        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, NULL,
        dwErr, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR) abErrMsg, sizeof(abErrMsg), NULL );

        printf("\nError code %u : \n%s\n", (unsigned int)dwErr, abErrMsg);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* -------------------------------*/

    /* Fills the structure with the starting addresses */

    int offset = 0;

    for (; offset < 10; offset++ ) { WriteToStruct->Addresses[offset] = (void *)BASE_ADDRESS + offset; }

    /* -------------------------------*/
    /* Return to main */

    return;
}

/* -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
```

The above code now works, but I would still like to find a way to search for specific bytes in memory. I'm not really sure how to approach this problem now unless I just define addresses with a debugger and keep stepping through until a find a match( via ReadProcessMemory ). Is this a valid way to do this? Or is there a better way? Please help me find a way to do this quickly and efficiently.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not the smallest program that illustrates the problem. For example the entire `cls` function appears completely unrelated.

Comment: I know, my compiler gives me a warning for not using it. I can always remove it, but I wasn't sure I wanted to depending on if I would add more user friendly graphics or if I needed to clear the screen at some point to print out new information. The VKEY thing at the beginning was meant to be used for later user-input, but I may decide not to use it at all depending on what I use this the most for.

Comment: Its fine to have the function in your program, but remove it from the program you post here because it is irrelevant. Reducing a program is part of your responsibility as the question-asker.

Comment: Should I post it again in a reduced way or leave it then?

Comment: Edit it down to the smallest program that still shows the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code makes no sense.

```
/* -------------------------------*/
/* Get the process's base address */

void * BaseAddress = ( void * ) MyProcess;
```

A process handle is not the same as a base address. If you debug your program, you'll see that your `BaseAddress` is probably a small number like 200, but if you look at the memory of the Minesweeper program, you'll see that it has no memory at address 200.

It looks like you're new to Windows programming. I would suggest that your first program not be a game cheat engine, which is an extraordinarily advanced topic. Try something much simpler.

Comment: I fixed my code, no more runtime errors. Also, I have already started with Pong( I haven't finished it yet, need to program the ball bouncing back and forth and a score system ). There is not really any other projects I think that would help me more other than my Pong project and this one.

Comment: You should work on other projects before trying to write a game-cheater. This is like saying "I just got my driver's license. I'm learning to drive a Toyota, and next I'm going to learn to drive a Formula 1. There aren't really any other cars that would help me learn more about driving."